# disable jquery plugin based on image dimension

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to disable jquery plugin based on the dimension of the image, so if the image is > 500x480 enable the plugin else if the image is lower than that disable the plugin.

What I tried isn't working. can someone help me out please?

The orginal function for the plugin

```
   $(function(){
    $('#zoom1').bind('click',function(){            
        var cloudZoom = $(this).data('CloudZoom');  
            cloudZoom.closeZoom();
            $.fancybox.open(cloudZoom.getGalleryList());// 
            return false;
        });
    });

         CloudZoom.quickStart();
```

What I tried,

```
 var img = document.getElementById('#zoom1'); 
 var width =  img.naturalWidth;
 var height = img.naturalHeight;
 $(function(){
    $('#zoom1').bind('click',function(){            
        var cloudZoom = $(this).data('CloudZoom');  
            cloudZoom.closeZoom();
            $.fancybox.open(cloudZoom.getGalleryList());// 
            return false;
        });
    });
 if(var width > 500 || height > 480) {
         CloudZoom.quickStart();//I would like to initiate this. 
         }
```

The html

```
  <div class="imgwrap">
 <div class="sldwrp">
        <div class="sldimgwrp">
        <?php if($result->num_rows > 0){ if ($row['image_one'] != '') {?>
        <img class="cloudzoom appsld" id ="zoom1" src="<?php echo $path.$row['image_one'];?>"
                 title="Click to view larger image."
                 data-cloudzoom='
                 zoomImage:"<?php echo $path.$row['image_one'];?>",
                 zoomSizeMode: "image",
                 captionPosition:"top",
                 maxMagnification:"4"
                 '><?php }}?>
                 </div>
        <div class="thumbs">
           <div class="thumb_img">
           <?php if($result->num_rows > 0){ if ($row['image_one'] != '') {?>
            <a href="<?php echo $path.$row['image_one'];?>" class="thumb-link">    
                <img class="cloudzoom-gallery" id="thumbwd" src="<?php echo $path.$row['image_one'];?>"
                     data-cloudzoom=' 
                     useZoom:"#zoom1",
                     image:"<?php echo $path.$row['image_one'];?>",
                     zoomImage:"<?php echo $path.$row['image_one'];?>"'>
            </a>
            <?php }}?>
```

Comment: Put your first three lines after `$(function(){`

Comment: @Brewal the plugin is completely disabled now. even though I have images greater than that dimension.

Answer (score 0):

You have several mistakes. Try this :

```
// fisrt mistake : you have to get the image dimensions when the dom element is created
// for this, put it after the $(function(){ 
$(function(){
    var img = document.getElementById('zoom1'); // second mistake here with the #zoom1 instead of just zoom1
    var width =  img.naturalWidth;
    var height = img.naturalHeight;

    $('#zoom1').bind('click',function(){
        if (width>500 || height>480) { // make your test here
            var cloudZoom = $(this).data('CloudZoom');  
            cloudZoom.closeZoom();
            $.fancybox.open(cloudZoom.getGalleryList());
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });

    CloudZoom.quickStart(); // leave this alone
});
```

Comment: Do you have any error in console ? Did you noticed your mistake : `document.getElementById('#zoom1');` instead of `document.getElementById('zoom1');` ? Try to `console.log` at each line and edit your question with the corresponding output

Comment: I did try that first and it doesn't work still, it says `[14:07:05.352] TypeError: img is null...` in the console.

Comment: What's your html ? (Because it seems like you have no `<img id="zoom1" />` element)

Comment: Okay I have updated the question with the html code, take a look.

Comment: Nice, but what is the html from the output ? You could have `$result->num_rows` equal to zero and then no `zoom1` image

Comment: Ho and remove your space after `id ="zoom1"`  => `id="zoom1"`

Comment: The php outputs the image and the image is visible, just the the zoom feature doesn't work.

Comment: Ok this is strange... At which line you got the error ? Because it's working fine for me : http://jsfiddle.net/BXyq3/